# ssl with apache2 using multisites

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, debian-jessie

Im testing startssl certificates to use inside apache2 with different sites.

I am using a simple config with virtualhosts (all really standard) inside apache2. Two domains tested are defined inside /etc/apache/sites-avaliable for example:

test1.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test1/
    ServerName www.test1.com

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_test1.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_test1.log combined
     RewriteEngine on
        ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
        RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin info@test1.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/test1/

        SSLEngine on
        SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
        SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ssl.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl_dec.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/sub.class1.server.ca.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

test2.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        DocumentRoot /var/www/test2/
        ServerName test2.com

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/wp_test2.log combined
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/wp_test2_error.log
    RewriteEngine off
        ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
        RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@test2.net
        DocumentRoot /var/www/test2/
        SSLEngine on
        SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
        SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/think.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/think_dec.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/sub.class1.server.ca.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

And I discover how the second domain not accepts the ssl certificate.

It appears error_bad_cert_doamin because says that test2 is using test1 certificate. If I use only one domain works perfectly. Where can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the server name in your SSL configuration too :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName test1.com
        ServerAdmin info@test1.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/test1/
        SSLEngine on
        SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
        SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ssl.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl_dec.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/sub.class1.server.ca.pem
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName test2.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@test2.net
        DocumentRoot /var/www/test2/
        SSLEngine on
        SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
        SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/think.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/think_dec.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/sub.class1.server.ca.pem
</VirtualHost>
```